# Zend framework - access controller or model from the view

Tags: zend-framework

I need to give the front-end designer the ability to choose whether or not to display a single xml feed or an mash-up, from the view.phtml file

This means I need to be able to call a method from the controller or model which then returns a variable to the view containing the requested feed(s).

So how do I access methods of the controller or model from the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't call controller methods in view , but you can create an instance of model (for read only purposes) inside view and then call its public methods  .eg

Foo.phtml

```
<?php $feedsTb = new Default_Model_Feeds() ?>
<?php $allFeeds = $feedsTb->fetchAll(); ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean "read only purposes"? Is this a bad practice? I have a script that parses some text and if it finds an image url, I want it to link to the image's homepage after finding its url in the database. Upon finding a URL in view, can I pass the url to the model this way and it be considered "ok"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i got your problem right, but this is something i'd probably do in a way like
Controller:

```
if($this->_getParam('single')) {
  $this->view->data = $model->getFeedSingleData();
  $this->render('single_feed.phtml');
} else { //mashup
  $this->view->data = $model->getMashUpData();
  $this-render('mashup_feed.phtml');
}
```

Though admittedly an example like this is better off with two different actions (`singleAction()` and `mashupAction()`)

But i really don't know if i got your problem figured out at all :S You may explain it further